# Python3 Urllib Http error 403 - except

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, исключения, urllib

Во время парсинга сайта, выкидывает ошибку 403:

```
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Видел "решение" с "юзер эджент" но оно не решает (у меня даже в браузере выскакивает такая ошибка на этом сайте).

Нужно именно железное решение в коде - в случае возникновения 403 ошибки (желательно и остальных) перезапустить код еще раз.

Проблема в том что except не улавливает ни `HTTPError`, ни `urllib.error.HTTPError`, ни `urllib.HTTPError`, ни `urllib.error`. В отличии от `ValueError`, `TypeError` и `IndexError` с которыми все ок работает.

В начале кода импортировал библиотеку с ошибками `from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError`"

Конкретный вопрос: как "отловить" эту ошибку 403?

Comment: Очень странно, что не срабатывает `except` с определенной ошибкой. Вы перепроверили всё? Может, ловите ошибку не там, бывает

Comment: Я новичек. Пробовал разные варианты как указывал выше. В IDLE ни один из этих вариантов не подсвечивается как "доступная" ошибка в отличии от того же IndexError и ему подобных. В английском сегменте сети читал что то про версии питона и урлиба + rise. Процитирую дословно: NOTE: Python 2.x urllib version also receives 403 status, but unlike Python 2.x urllib2 and Python 3.x urllib, it does not raise the exception. You can confirm that by following code: 
print(urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()) # => 403  Что имелось ввиду под с последним примером кода не понятно, и куда его писать и чем поможет

Comment: Кстати, пробовали с `urllib2`? `from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError`. В крайнем случае, если ничего не получается, ловите ошибку просто с помощью `except Exception as e`. И внутри можно обработать ошибку.

Comment: спасибо! А можете объяснить подробнее про это: except Exception as e. - что это? Как оно работает? Ибо urllib2 у меня не стоит index error ругается. У меня python 3.5 на анаконде

Comment: В документации вот что пишут: Handling Exceptions
urlopen raises URLError when it cannot handle a response (though as usual with Python APIs, built-in exceptions such as ValueError, TypeError etc. may also be raised).

HTTPError is the subclass of URLError raised in the specific case of HTTP URLs.

The exception classes are exported from the urllib.error module.

Comment: про `Exception as e` посмотрите [пример](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions). Внутри этого блока вы можете по-разному, например, обработать исключение `e`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37391/discussion-between-approximatenumber-and-amaroc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time

while True:
    try:
        with urlopen(URL) as f:
            print(f.read())
        
        # Прошло без ошибок, выходим
        break

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
  
        # Ждем 30 секунд перед повтором запроса
        time.sleep(30)
```

Можно дальше – ограничить количество повторов, отлавливать и обрабатывать индивидуально разные исключения, увеличивать таймауты между повторами для повторяющихся ошибок

Comment: Да вот советовали уже:
 except Exception as e:
        print(e)

Но я абсолютно не могу понять  логику работы этого кода. Что он делает? Мне так его и занести? То-есть этот код если (по моему разумению) вводить то он "при выводе "Любой" абсолютно ошибке - начнет печатать print(e)? Я его добавил , urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden так и выходит (после print(e) само собой необходимые мне действия на перезапуск функции.

Comment: Конструкция `except` -- ловит исключение, `Exception` -- базовое исключение, которое позволит поймать любое исключение, внутри `except` описываются действия при отлове исключения. В моем примере просто пишется текст ошибки в консоль и выполняется задержка программы на 30 секунд, чтобы после снова попытаться скачать

Comment: спасибо за подробное объяснение, я понял. Но дело в том что я пробовал аналогичный код "except Exception as e:" с дальнейшими инструкциями но на ошибку Urllib.error.http - ни как не повлияло - она выскакивала, и ни каких "принтов", или действий далее не было. Видимо она не инициализируется как базовая ошибка. Причем в английских коментариях по смыслу понял что так оно и есть, в версии urllib для python 3+.  Думаю два  других ответа (со схожим) кодом - должны сработать.

Comment: @Amaroc извините, я вас обманул. `BaseException` -- основное исключение. Перепутал с c#, у которого `Exception` базовый

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть возможность использовать `urrlib2`, отлавливайте код ошибки `urllib2.HTTPError`. Например:

```
import urllib2
import time

try:
   do_something()
except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
   if e.code == 403:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
        do_something()
else:
   raise
```

Либо ловить [код](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/urllib.error.html) ошибки `urllib.error.HTTPError` :

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
import time

try:
   do_something()
except HTTPError as e:
   if e.code == 403:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(TIMEOUT)
        do_something()
else:
   raise
```

Comment: В python3 нет модуля urllib2

Comment: @gil9red ну, отсутствующий модуль - это далеко не проблема (`pip install urllib2`).

Comment: И все-равно, pip не установит utllib2 на python3, который у автора

Comment: @gil9red я пропустил отредактированный коммент автора про python35.

Comment: @approximatenumber спасибо большое! Завтра буду тестировать, правильные ответы (подошедшее) помечу как полагается!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все варианты подходят!

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPError` работает:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

try:
    urlopen('http://httpbin.org/status/403')
except HTTPError as e:
    assert e.code == 403
else:
    assert 0, 'never happens'
```

Чтобы повторить запрос `max_attempts` раз в случае получения 403 Forbidden HTTP статуса:

```
for _ in range(max_attempts):
    try:
        response = urlopen(url)
    except HTTPError as e:
        if e.code == 403:
            last_error = e
            continue  # try again
        raise  # allow other errors to propagate up the stack
    else:  # success
        break
else:  # no break: all attempts failed
    raise last_error  # raise last error
```